# Copy all directories except one

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command, cp

I'm copying all subdirectories with its contents to my current directory as follows:

```
cp -r dirToCopy/* .
```

But in the folder `dirToCopy`, there is one subfolder called `dirNotToCopy` which should not be copied.

How can I filter that particular folder out of my expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r dirToCopy/!(dirNotToCopy) .
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to do it in **single line:**

```
find /path_to/dirToCopy -mindepth 1 -type d  ! -name dirNotToCopy -exec cp -r {} . \;
```

One more way of doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path_to/dirToCopy -maxdepth 1 -type d  ! -name dirNotToCopy -exec cp -r {} . \;
```

Instead of using mindepth suggested in the other answer, we should use maxdepth.
(I can't comment or edit another answer since I do not have enough reputation yet)

Also note that this command only copies the subdirectories, not the files in the directory.